# How to read local pdf files on android using Flex application

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, pdf, flexbuilder

I have a Flex application running on iOS and Android devices.
On iOS devices, it is possible to read a pdf using a stagewebview.

On a android device (Galaxy Tab2 with Android ICS, I have a blank screen.

I have read many things about this issue. But I don't know if the bug is still present or if I have to implement the ANE for this issue.

If there is someone who solves this issue, I'd be very king if he could give any answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to display the PDF?  Or access/manipulate it's content via ActionScript somehow?  I was pretty sure that StageWebView made use of the browser on the OS.  Do mobile browsers display PDFs?  Or do they launch other apps to do that?

Comment: I want to display it. With StageWebView, I have a blank screen. Android web browser doesn't display it. It downloads the pdf file. the user has to launch a pdf viewer to display the pdf file.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with this? I've tried all the workarounds (copying file to local storage, to temp folder, using stageWebViewBridge) but it's not working :-( I saw an adobe employee suggest this is impossible... not a word I like!